# PHP coding procedural vs object oriented

Tags: php, object-model

Procedural coding vs object oriented.
Which is the best from the application point of view?
Can an application function better with an object oriented coding? or be slower?

Comment: thies question is kinda subjective, there is no right answer as it really depends on the exact situation. Do you have a specific scenario where this applies, or can you be more specific.

Comment: Your question isn't really answerable without a problem to solve.  A similar question in this line of thought might be asking "Does it make sense to write software around design patterns or design software by writing patterns."

Answer (score 2):

Don't think there is a 'best' here. Each have their own use and should be explored depending on what the context of the application is.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the kind of application you are building. If the application is very simple one, (e.g. add_two_nums(x,y)) then OO is overkill. There are times when a very simple application starts expanding and becomes a complicated one. If there is a chalked out plan of such scenario, then OO is better because even though initially it seems overkill, in future, it will help to expand the application with ease. I have not seen any performance issues between procedural style and OO approach. Someone might throw some light into it.